# Devise Sign Up - Fields say "can't be blank"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Good Morning,

I've got an issue with my sign up. I've been manually testing it and the sign up is not pulling through the fields. I've set up the strong params and I've also tried it without them and using the old attr_accessible but it doesn't make a difference.

Has anyone else had this issue before?

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception


  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :profile_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation,
        :confirmation_token, :confirmed_at, :confirmation_sent_at) }
 end
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :create_rank
  devise :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

  attr_accessible :provider, :uid

  validates :first_name, :last_name, :profile_name, presence: true
 # validates :email, presence: true,
             #  :format => { :with => /^([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})$/i, :on => :create },
              # :uniqueness => true,
               #:multiline => true
  validates :password, :presence => true,
                       :confirmation => true,
                       :length => {:within => 6..40},
                       :on => :create
  validates :password, :confirmation => true,
                       :length => {:within => 6..40},
                       :allow_blank => true,
                       :on => :update

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :registerable, :confirmable
```

I'm very lost and not sure why this issue is happening, I don't think it's the form but please see the form below.

devise/registrations/new.html.erb

```
div class="span12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span3">   
            <div class="verticaldivide">
<h2 style="color:white;">Sign up</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => "form-vertical"}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.input :first_name, :required => true, :autofocus => true, label: false, placeholder: "Bilbo", :input_html => {:class => "form-control"} %>
    <br />
    <%= f.input :last_name, :required => true, :autofocus => true, label: false, placeholder: "Baggins", :input_html => {:class => "form-control"} %>
    <br />
    <%= f.input :profile_name, :required => true, :autofocus => true, label: false, placeholder: "Bilbo18...", :input_html => {:class => "form-control"} %>
    <br />
    <%= f.input :email, :required => true, :autofocus => true, label: false, placeholder: "Email please...", :input_html => {:class => "form-control"} %>
    <br />
    <%= f.input :password, :required => true, label: false, placeholder: "Enter Password", :input_html => {:class => "form-control"} %>
    <br />
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :required => true, label: false, placeholder: "Confirm Password!", :input_html => {:class => "form-control"} %>
    <br />
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up", :class => 'btn-primary' %>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
<% end %>

 <div class="span3">
    <h2 style="color:white;">Link Up</h2>
  <%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %>
       </div>
    </div>
```

User schema:

```
 create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "rank",                   default: "0"
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "profile_name"
    t.boolean  "admin",                  default: false
    t.integer  "sash_id"
    t.integer  "level",                  default: 0
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["confirmation_token"], name: "index_users_on_confirmation_token", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree

end
```

Comment: are you leaving any of these fields empty - `first_name, last_name, profile_name`???

Comment: Nope, I'm manually entering full details in each one.

Comment: why this two times..`validates :password` 1st time with validation as presence => true and 2nd time excluding presence validation?? why is it two times

Comment: That allows blank password confirmation :on => :update for user editing but I tried hashing it out and manually submitting another form with no luck :(

Comment: remove the presence validation from the 1st one also and give a try

Comment: Ok I've commented out all the validation and now I only get it with e-mail field and password field?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40300/discussion-between-amit-karsale-and-shaun-frost-duke-jackson)